# Would oxygen levels be stable without photosynthesis?

Tags: ecology, climate-change

I learned how the CO$_2$ cycle works in several biology classes, high school, elementary school, geology, and physics. Then today there was an [article published in the NY Times](http://www.nytimes.com/2014/09/20/opinion/to-save-the-planet-dont-plant-trees.html) claiming:

> ...it is a myth that photosynthesis controls the amount of oxygen in the atmosphere. Even if all photosynthesis on the planet were shut down, the atmosphere's oxygen content would change by less than 1 percent.

I'm really confused. If the earth naturally has 20% oxygen in the absence of photosynthisis, why did it spike durring [Great Oxygenation Event](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Oxygenation_Event)? I reread that several times. There's no citation; no further context that can explain this. If this were coming from the climate change denier camp, I'd just shrug it off, but the credentials would say otherwise. It's in the NY Times and [Nadine Unger](http://environment.yale.edu/profile/nadine-unger/) is an atmospheric chemist at Yale.

My guess is that this is simply a misleading paragraph with a grain of truth. The question is, where is that grain? How long would the atmospheric oxygen content remain at within 1% of the current level if we turned off photosynthesis?

Answer (score 6):

The answer to your question is in the first graph of the Wikipedia article you linked to: [Great Oxygenation Event](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Oxygenation_Event). In that graph, where time is measures in billions of years, you see that O<sub>2</sub>, as it was produced, was absorbed in oceans, seabed rock, land surfaces, and finally, about .85 billion years ago, *O<sub>2</sub> sinks filled* and the gas accumulated in the atmosphere.<sup>[1]</sup> The spike you speak of was probably due to

> the evolution of the large vascular land plants that brought about increased O<sub>2</sub> production and increased O<sub>2</sub> levels due to the enhanced global burial of microbially resistant, lignin-rich organic matter during the Permo–Carboniferous (Berner 2004).

More simply put, there hadn't been equilibrium established yet between the amount of oxygen being produced, the stabilization of the ocean layers and the 'burial of excess carbon' in the deepest ocean layers. Most of the O<sub>2</sub> on earth was produced many millions of years ago; it is a myth that the O<sub>2</sub> we breathe today is the same O<sub>2</sub> made by, say, ocean phytoplankton yesterday.

Nadene Unger states in the [NYT article](http://www.nytimes.com/2014/09/20/opinion/to-save-the-planet-dont-plant-trees.html?_r=0) that

> [I]t is a myth that photosynthesis controls the amount of oxygen in the atmosphere. Even if all photosynthesis on the planet were shut down, the atmosphere’s oxygen content would change by less than 1 percent.

This is because there are tremendous *oxygen sinks* that store oxygen gas, such as the surface layers of the ocean. As O<sub>2</sub> is used, the ocean would give up free O<sub>2</sub>. Because of these sinks, some estimate that

> if photosynthesis were to cease, atmospheric oxygen would be depleted in 5000 years due to respiration, weathering, and combustion.<sup>[2]</sup>

while others state that

> If photosynthesis were for some reason to stop, oxidation of the entire organic carbon reservoir would consume less than 1% of O<sub>2</sub> presently in the atmosphere and there would be no further O<sub>2</sub> loss (since there would be no organic carbon left to be oxidized). Conversely, if respiration and decay were to stop, conversion of all atmospheric CO<sub>2</sub> to O<sub>2</sub> by photosynthesis would increase O<sub>2</sub> levels by only 0.2%.<sup>[3]</sup>

It is very hard to get a comprehensive answer of what would happen exactly. Do we assume all vegetation/phytoplankton suddenly disappears, or does it die (thus increasing to the carbon drain on O<sub>2</sub>)? Do we assume quick quick death of animals based on lack of vegetation/plankton, etc. as food, or would it be slower? As I said, a comprehensive answer is difficult to find. In any case, the atmospheric O<sub>2</sub> would not fluctuate wildly in any immediate fashion.

<sub>[1] [The oxygenation of the atmosphere and oceans](http://rstb.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/361/1470/903.full.pdf) Heinrich D Holland, Phil. Trans. R. Soc., 29 June 2006</sub>
<sub>[2] [The Global Oxygen Cycle](http://paos.colorado.edu/~fasullo/pjw_class/oxygencycle6.html)</sub>
<sub>[3] [Introduction to Atmospheric Chemistry](http://acmg.seas.harvard.edu/people/faculty/djj/book/bookchap6.html)</sub>

Comment: So basically Unger's claim is based around the ideas in third reference (The last link is worth a read): carbon is the limiting reagent in the C + O2 -> CO2 reaction? My gut reaction is that in the absence of photosynthesis we don't live in a bistable system: we'd eventually return to the state from billions of years ago. But I can believe that _initially_ there would be very little change.

Comment: Also, maybe worth clarifying what "the entire organic carbon reservoir" is referring to. I'm assuming it means all life on earth, plus all fossil fuels we could conceivably dig up.

Comment: @Shep, yes, I believe you're right. In other times, other things also needed O2, like iron, etc. but now, it's mostly carbon.